# Esbuild is not able to bundle function with optional parameter with default value

Tags: javascript, typescript, esbuild

Given an interface function with an optional parameter receiving a default/fallback value

```
interface DataProvider {
    getEntities: ({ foo, skip = 0, bar, }: { foo: any; skip?: number; bar?: any; }) => Promise<GetEntitiesResult>;
}
```

Building the project via

> tsc

works fine. But when trying to bundle it via

> esbuild ./lib/index.ts --bundle --minify --sourcemap --target=es2022 --format=esm --outfile=./bundle/index.esm.js

throws the error

> ✘ [ERROR] Unexpected "="

Does someone know what's wrong or missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some compatibility issue between esbuild and tsc, did you try to use an explicit default value instead of the shorthand syntax?

```
interface DataProvider {
  getEntities: ({ foo, skip, bar }: { foo: any; skip?: number; bar?: any }) => Promise<GetEntitiesResult>;
}

// In your implementation:
getEntities({ foo, skip = 0, bar }: { foo: any; skip?: number; bar?: any }) {
  // ...
}
```